# I can't get value with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, geolocation, navigator

I want get my system geolocation every 5 seconds with useEffect,
but I don't know why the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition did not arrive,
am I wrong?

```
const getPosition = () => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
            reject();
        } else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                console.log('did not arrive here');
                const { latitude } = position.coords.latitude;
                const { longitude } = position.coords.longitude;
                resolve({ latitude,longitude });
            })
        };
    })
    .then(async value => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = value;
        const data = await axios.get(`http://10.0.0.54:8000/api?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}`);
        return data.data
    })
};

export default function Weather() {
    const [observationalData, setObservationalData] = useState({
        stationId: '',
        stationName: '',
        timestamp: 0,
        time: '',
        observationDate: '',
        observationTime: '',
        temperature: 0,
        weather: '',
        title: '',
        humidity: 0
    });

    console.log(getPosition());

    useEffect(()=> {
        const timer = setInterval(getPosition, 5000);
        console.log(new Date());
    
        return ()=> {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      });
    
      useEffect(()=> {
        setObservationalData(getPosition());
        console.log(observationalData);
      }, []);
}
```

the console.log('did not arrive here') did not work, so I can't resolve that promise,
when call useEffect, I just get "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default function Weather() {
  const [observationalData, setObservationalData] = useState({
    stationId: "",
    stationName: "",
    timestamp: 0,
    time: "",
    observationDate: "",
    observationTime: "",
    temperature: 0,
    weather: "",
    title: "",
    humidity: 0,
  });

  var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0,
  };

  const getPosition = (data) => {
    //use data to destructure
    //setObservationalData(customdata);
  };

  function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(getPosition, 5000);
    console.log(new Date());

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, error, options);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: it still not work, I get only undefined

Comment: Did you tried logging `data` inside `getPosition` function ?